# Powershell remote installation of exe files but it never finishes

Tags: powershell, installation, remote-access

Ok, so I have a problem currently where I am trying to remotely deploy and run exe files remotely. I have a Ninite installation of just a simple 7zip on it, which I wanna install, and for now I have gotten so close that it even executes the file, but it never finishes the installation. I can see it in the Task Manager, but it never makes any progress, nor does it use any CPU, only a small bit of memory.

The code looks like this:

```
Copy-item -path C:\windows\temp\installer.exe -destination 'c:\users\administrator\desktop\installer -tosession
start-sleep -seconds 2
invoke-command -computername MyPc -scriptblock { $(& cmd c/ 'c:\users\administrator\desktop\installer\installer.exe' -silent -wait -passthru | select Exitcode }
$session | remove-possession
```

this runs, but it never stops running. the script just constantly runs without ever finishing. If I go and look in the Task Manager, I can clearly see both(?) the installation files going on somewhere, but it doesn't do anything but just sit there and never finishes. I have now tried to let it sit for about 15 minutes (the installation takes about 2-3 min at max) and still, no progress.

[image: Here's a picture of the task manager.]

Any ideas as to what could cause this? or atleast how to fix it and let it finish. this is the last thing I need to get done in my project and this is done and I am so tired of this already.

NOTE: I have found out that if I have ANY kind of parameters (-wait, -passthru, etc) then it will become stuck forever with 0 CPU usage, even if i just have argumentlist attached with 0 arguments it will do the same, but if i have nothing but the command in the scriptblock, then it will go through, say "done master" and then be the biggest liar because the software has not been installed, it just closed the installer instead.

Comment: It's likely waiting for user input. If you `enter-pssession` and execute the installer as same user, does it work as expected?

Comment: right now i can't get it to work no matter what i do. After further testing, it seems like it is some kind of parameter problem. If i have no parameters on it (like -wait, etc) then it finishes, but doesn't actually install the program, but as soon as i have any parameter on, it will sit and just do nothing for all eternity.

note: just found out that even without any parameters, but just having argumentlist is enough for it to get stuck.

Comment: You forgot to enter the session object for parameter `-ToSession` and there is a typo with `remove-possession` (should be `Remove-PSSession`)

Comment: the typo is because i couldn't copy my code, so i had to write it in hand, hence the typo i made, but in the code it is as it should be (Remove-PSSession), but the problem is that if i add ANY parameters to the sentence, then it will get stuck for all eternity. If i use no parameters, it goes through, but does not install the actual software, it just runs the installer, after a few seconds exits the installer, and then nothing. nothing is installed and nothing happened.

Comment: You are copying the file from your local pc to... your local pc. Why would a remote computer be able to find the installer on _**ITS**_ path `c:\users\administrator\desktop\installer\installer.exe` ?? Best put the installer.exe in a folder on an accessible file share and have the remote machine(s) run it from there

Comment: the problem isn't as much as it can't find the file, the main problem is that it fails to finish the installation after it runs the .exe file. Found out that alot of people says it is impossible, since i (and alot of other people) hits some kind of environmental snag. 
also tried with making a scheduled task, but then it never launches the .exe file, no matter the location or if it is on a fileshare.